# Simplifying $\exp(a)\ln(b)$

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

I am working on simplifying a problem, and I ran into $\exp(a)\ln(b)$. Here's what I tried:
$$\exp(a)\ln(b)$$
$$\ln(\exp(\exp(a)))\ln(b)$$
I also tried:
$$\exp(a)\ln(b)$$
$$\exp(a)\exp(\ln(\ln(b)))$$
$$\exp(a+\ln(\ln(b)))$$
Are there any other formulas for $\exp(a)\ln(b)$?

Comment: Why do you expect it to be simplified further?  It seems simple enough already.

Comment: It might be better to give more about the context in which this showed up. Might you have made an error?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't actually $\,\exp(a\ln(b))=b^a\,$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe your first expression is equivalent, for example:

$$e^2 \cdot \ln(3) = 8.12$$

$$\ln(e^{e^2} + 3) = 7.39$$

This is because $(\ln x)(\ln y) \neq \ln(x+y),$ which you did in your second step. As for finding a more simple expression, I think the one you started with is pretty much as good as it gets. Some other options I've devised for you include:

$$e^a \ln b = \ln(e^{e^a}) \ln b = \ln\left((e^{e^a})^{\ln b}\right) = \ln \left(e^{(e^{e^a})^{\ln b}}\right)$$

which, after enough reducing, gives me $\ln b \ \cdot \ e^a$

Answer (score 0):

The simplest form is $e^{a}\ln(b)$.

Following from what you've done, we have: $e^{a}\ln(b)$=$e^{a+\ln(\ln(b))}$=$\ln(e^{e^{a}})\ln(b)$=$e^{\ln(\ln(b)e^{a})}$=$\ln(e^{\ln(b)e^{a}})$.